# FactoryGirl before(:create) callback not creating associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a FactoryGirl factory, that creates a `Order` but the before(:create) callback does not create the associated factory object:

**Parent Class**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tax, :total
  has_many :order_lines

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :order_lines , presence: true
end
```

**Child Class**

```
class OrderLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order, :product, :qty
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  ...
  ...
  validates :order, presence: true
end
```

**Factory**

```
Factory :order do
  ...
  ignore do
    number_or_order_lines 1
  end
  before(:create) do |order, evaluator|
    FactoryGirl.create_list :order_line, evaluator.number_or_order_lines, order: order
  end
end

Factory :order_line do
   association :user
   association :order
   ...
end
```

**PROBLEM**

In my rspec test, if I create a order object:

```
describe Order do
  before {@order = FactoryGirl.create(:order) }  => #throws error (see below)
end
```

**ERROR**
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
Validation failed Order Lines can't be blank

**UPDATE**

I can however successfully do the following but obviously only accomplishes creating one:

```
after(:build) do |order, evaluator|
  order.order_lines << FactoryGirl.build(:order_line, order: order)
end
```

**Hypothesis** -  I can see where the `create_list` might be attempting to save the `OrderLine` which would cause an error since the parent hasn't been saved - but I don't know if it still returns a OrderLine object that is just in an invalid state and therefore the order_lines collection on the order object should still not be empty.

Comment: Try using after(:build) instead of before(:create)

Comment: Updating the problem with new information - I have tried the after(:build) as well as using build_list instead of create_list.  Unfortunately, the only way it will work if the validation for order_lines on the Order model.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 8):

You need to put your OrderLine factory into the order record like this

```
Factory :order do
    ...
    ignore do
      number_or_order_lines 1
    end
    before(:create) do |order, evaluator|
      order.order_lines << (FactoryGirl.create :order_line, order: order)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me :)